# NaN value from Js function on checkbox click for price total

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the total of the price of checkbox values given to the function. My value attribute stores the id of my database so I can not assign a price to the value tag.

```js
function UpdateCost(elem) {
   
  let total = Number(elem.value);
  if (isNaN(total)) {
    total = 0;
  }
  if (elem.checked === true) {
    total += Number(elem.value);
  } else {
    total -= Number(elem.value);
  }

    alert(total);
  document.getElementById('total').value = total.toFixed(0);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="UpdateCost(20);" /> Price = 20
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="UpdateCost(25);" /> Price = 25
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="UpdateCost(30);" /> Price = 30
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="UpdateCost(20);" /> Price = 40
  <input  type=text id=total value=0>  
</form>
```

Comment: You're using `elem.value` but you're passing `20` for `elem`. Numbers do not have a `.value` property.

Comment: why you didn't pass the price value to the `value` attribute? Any specific reason?

Comment: i have store the id in value attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-` attributes to achieve it.

```js
let total = 0;

function UpdateCost(element) {
  if (element.checked === true) {
    total += Number(element.getAttribute('data-price'));
  } else {
    total -= Number(element.getAttribute('data-price'));
  }
  
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total.toFixed(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="20" /> Price = 20
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="25" /> Price = 25
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="30" /> Price = 30
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="40" /> Price = 40
    <div id="total"> </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

For decimal use `parseFloat()`

```js
let total = 0;

function UpdateCost(element) {
  if (element.checked === true) {
    total = total + parseFloat(element.getAttribute('data-price'));
  } else {
    total -= parseFloat(element.getAttribute('data-price'));
  }
  
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total.toFixed(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="20.2" /> Price = 20.2
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="25.4" /> Price = 25.4
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="30.6" /> Price = 30.6
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" data-price="40.8" /> Price = 40.8
    <div id="total"> </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

https://jsfiddle.net/3xq8zojg/

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" /> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" /> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" /> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" /> 
  <div id="total"> </div>
</form>


var total = 0;
function UpdateCost(elem) {
alert(elem.value);

if (elem.checked === true) {
total = total+Number(elem.value);
} else {
total = total -Number(elem.value);
}
console.log(total)

    document.getElementById('total').value = total.toFixed(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function:

```
function UpdateCost() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox[]');
    var len = checkboxes.length;

    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            result = result + Number(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = result;
}
```